# Progress bar with changing images in framer-motion (React with TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I have an application in React using TypeScript and Framer-Motion. Does anyone know how I can achieve an effect like the section below on framer.com? I've tried with a progress bar, unfortunately I can't create such a section. I am specifically looking to map these elements with three images and three progress bars.

Link to section: https://www.framer.com/#design-1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the scroll references and animations, as well give different heights other than the visible:

https://www.framer.com/motion/scroll-animations/

as @Soheildev, easier with three.js

Answer (score -1):

you can use frameworks like three.js chart.js anime.js
If you use it, you can implement it to some extent like that link